# cPanel MariaDB connection fails with node.js mysql connector

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mariadb, cpanel

I am trying to host a express.js app which connects to maria db. In my local computer, I can successfully execute queries on my local MariaDB. But when I try to do same on host machine (uses cPanel) It's failing with this error.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at /home/gaziokcu/express/routes/index.js:32:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/gaziokcu/nodevenv/express/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
/home/gaziokcu/express/routes/index.js:33
  if (err) throw err;
```

Code I used for connection:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user:'user', 
        password: '<password>',
        database:'<database>',
    });
```

Even if write 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' to host, connector is trying to connect with '127.0.0.1'. My DB administrator says I must connect with 'localhost' keyword due to network config.

How can I solve this problem ?

**Edit:**

I can connect to database with PHP using localhost and 3306 settings.

Comment: You need to get the IP for the DB connection.
Localhost is not the right one.

Comment: @Talg123 But  I can connect on my local PC using localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Most other connectors map localhost to the unix socket.

nodejs has a [socketPath](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) option that connects to the mariadb unix socket.

I'm assuming in your configuration that MariaDB isn't listening on 3306.

Comment: I can connect database in php using localhost:3306, admin said that I must use localhost, not 127.0.0.1 and when I try to connect using node.js libraries, they are trying to connect with 127.0.0.1 even if I write 'localhost' to hostname and 3306 to portname.

Comment: and he also said there is no socketPath available

Comment: If php is connecting to `localhost` then its using a socket. Use php_info to display what the default socket is and use that in nodejs.

Comment: hello @danblack, I also tried socketPath /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock and /tmp/mysql.sock but it is not working. phpinfo say it is in /var/lib/mysql folder.

Comment: not working as in ECONNREFUSED? `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` might be other location is the host is Debian/Ubuntu based, however /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` is usually Red Hat/Fedora/Centos based. `/tmp/mysql.sock` is another possibility.

Comment: it's too weird that admin said there is no socket path, but phpinfo say  there is. It's Centos based. I think I am switching to sqlite.

Comment: Sounds like you should switch admin that can't give concrete advice on their system.